# Why is this code for implementing mergesort not producing correct result?

Tags: c

Here in I'm trying to implement mergesort on array of 10 elements. On providing the input a[10]={9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0} , I obtain the output as {0,0,1,1,0, 4,4,4,3,2} while the expected output is {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}. I am calling the mergesort in main with l=0,h=9.

```
void mergesort(int a[],int l,int h)
    {   
      int c[10];
      int m=(l+h)/2;
      if(l<h)
      { 
            mergesort(a,l,m);           // Recursive call to sort first half
            mergesort(a,m+1,h);         // Recursive call to sort second half
        }
        int i,k=l,j=l;
        while(k<=h)                        // Merging the first and second half of the array
        {   
            if(a[j]<a[m+1])
            {
                c[k]=a[j];
                k++;
                j++;
            }
            else
            {
                c[k]=a[m+1];
                k++;
                m++;
            }       
        }
        for(i=l;i<=h;i++)
            a[i]=c[i];  
    }
```

Comment: How do you call this the first time? Please show a complete example (also known as a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Maybe you could try debugging it?

Answer (score 1):

One of the few problems: Your value of `l` is no longer a valid left limit after the while loop since you are incrementing it. So when you are copying from array `c` to `a` later in the for loop, you are copying invalid data.

Comment: I changed my code to correct for that mistake, however the program still isn't producing the required output.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your while loop you are sometimes looking outside the bounds you should be.

Assuming you put in a check at the beginning of your function saying if l==h then return (since sorting a one element array is unnecessary) then the first time it will do anything is when it recurses to `mergesort(a, 0,1)`. Here we are basically merging two single element arrays.

When going through your loop the first time we have `i,j,k,m=0`. We will go into the else part of the if because element 0 is greater than 1. We thus write out a[1] into the output array and we now have `i,j=0` and `k,m=1`. What we now should do is note that our second array is exhausted and fill from the remaining elements in the first array.

Instead what we do is compare elements `j` and `m+1` (ie 0 and 2). This is clearly wrong because element 2 shouldn't appear in the array. We of course find element 2 is smaller and thus put that into the output array at position two. Once we copy this over a we get `{8, 7, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0}` and this is where it all goes wrong.